# Should Text Format: "Full HTML" create a safe value?

Tags: 7

When I am rendering fields I noticed that if the user selects "full html" as the WSYWIG text format on a "long text" field, a safe value is not created. 
For example the array would be:

```
value (String, 14 characters ) <div>test</div> 
format (String, 9 characters ) full_html
```

But if "Filtered HTML" input selected it would be:

```
value (String, 14 characters ) <div>test</div> 
format (String, 9 characters ) full_html
safe_value (String, 4 characters ) test
```

Settings to Full HTML seem to have no effect.

What controls whether a safe value is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core text module does. This logic is driven by the text module's [`text_field_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21text%21text.module/function/text_field_load/7.x), an invocation of [`hook_field_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_load/7.x). When the module loads text fields it looks up the filters used for the text format and sees if it's cacheable (i.e. if it saves to `safe_value`).

In your case, the logic is being triggered by toggling the `filtered_html` / `full_html` formats. Because raw HTML is potentially unsafe, it's not stored in the `save_value` cache.
`